# CNN Nettrain problem

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I 500 pictures of tables and chairs each (849x849) and want to train a convolutional neural net to classify new pictures accordingly. This is my code so far:

```
cfiles = Import["D:\\Mathematica11\\bo_sample\\chairs\\*"];
tfiles = Import["D:\\Mathematica11\\bo_sample\\tables\\*"];

$train = 300;
trainingData = Join[
 Thread[cfiles[[;; $train]] -> "chairs"],
 Thread[tfiles[[;; $train]] -> "tables"]
 ];
testingData = Join[
  Thread[cfiles[[$train + 1 ;;]] -> "chairs"] ,
  Thread[tfiles[[$train + 1 ;;]] -> "tables"]
  ];

lenet = NetChain[{ConvolutionLayer[20, 5], 
              Ramp, 
              PoolingLayer[2, 2], 
              ConvolutionLayer[50, 5], 
              Ramp, 
              PoolingLayer[2, 2], 
              FlattenLayer[],
              500, 
              Ramp, 
              2, 
              SoftmaxLayer[]}, 
              "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[0, 1]}], 
              "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {849, 849}, "RGB"}]];


trainedNN =  NetTrain[lenet, trainingData, ValidationSet -> testingData,  MaxTrainingRounds -> 3];

...Failure GPU Memory exhausted
```

It seems the usage of NetTrain is not correct in both cases but the error-messages are not clear to me. Can someone take a look please?

Comment: Probably you need to `NetInitialize` your graph first.

Comment: Hi. I tried initNN = NetInitialize[lenet] but I get the same error-message with trainedNN.

Comment: `RandomSample` doesn't work as you expect there, fix it first.

Comment: I deleted the first NetTrain segment (lenet = NetTrain[lenet, RandomSample.... which produced the first error message. This was just a different approach which did not work. Actually I would prefer the second approach with trainedNN = NetTrain... to work.

Comment: Reverse the arrows in your `Association`, outputs should be on the right.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make proper data format as list of rules $(Image \rightarrow Class)$

   ```
   trainingData = Join[
       Thread[cfiles[[;; $train]] -> "chairs"],
       Thread[tfiles[[;; $train]] -> "tables"]
   ];
   testingData = Join[
       Thread[cfiles[[$train + 1 ;;]] -> "chairs"] ,
       Thread[tfiles[[$train + 1 ;;]] -> "tables"]
   ];
   ```
2. `NetDecoder` should look like this

   ```
   NetDecoder[{"Class", {"chairs", "tables"}}]
   ```

This works for me:

```
cfiles = Array[RandomImage[1, {100, 100}] &, {100}, 
   ColorSpace -> "RGB"];
tfiles = Array[RandomImage[1, {100, 100}] &, {100}, 
   ColorSpace -> "RGB"];

$train = 80;
trainingData = Join[
   Thread[cfiles[[;; $train]] -> "chairs"],
   Thread[tfiles[[;; $train]] -> "tables"]
   ];
testingData = Join[
   Thread[cfiles[[$train + 1 ;;]] -> "chairs"] ,
   Thread[tfiles[[$train + 1 ;;]] -> "tables"]
   ];
lenet = NetChain[{ConvolutionLayer[20, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2], 
    ConvolutionLayer[50, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2], FlattenLayer[],
     500, Ramp, 2, SoftmaxLayer[]}, 
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"chairs", "tables"}}], 
   "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {100, 100}, "RGB"}]];
trainedNN = 
 NetTrain[lenet, trainingData, ValidationSet -> testingData, 
  MaxTrainingRounds -> 3]
```

Comment: I tried your code but still get the same error.

Comment: I tried your code. It works but if I use it on my imported pictures I get error-message GPU memory exhausted. I probably have to resize them because your trainingset is smaller and also the size of the random images.

Comment: Ok. The training is now running. Thx for the support.